# convert text to UpperCase in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to convert the text entered in textbox to uppercase, but I am not getting the output,please help.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PanNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);" })
```

Comment: show InputToUpper method

Comment: You also can do this with css, style = "text-transform: uppercase"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work (remove `@onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);"` from the `TextBoxFor` method)

```
$('#PanNumber').keyup(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(text.toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "@editorfor" text box then try

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PanNumber.Alias, new { 
       htmlAttributes = new { @class = "upper-case" }
})
```